# "Submit"s don't work after setting up <httpRuntime maxRequestLength />

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I needed to upload rather big file(s) to the server, so I added

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
```

to `Web.Config` file. After that I managed to upload needed file. But the problem is that after I added `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />` all other `Submit`s began to result in sending empty http requests to the servers. At least it looks like that (Opera dragonfly showed empty http request, but debugger didn't react to the breakpoint placed inside the controller, which must've happened; and no errors were displayed by opera).

Comment: Did you make any other changes around the same time?

Comment: No, I just worked with controller.

Comment: if the debugger didn't react ( and it is setup correctly ) the request is not getting to your controller

Comment: I understand it, but that's quite strange. I still can upload file, so submit  works for one form and it doesn't for others.

Comment: you are using `IIS6` or `IIs7`? if it works for one request and not for others try adjusting the `appRequestQueueLimit` also set the appropriate `executionTimeout="7200"`

Comment: Not an answer to your original question, but rather a tip so that you can make sure what is exactly going on between the server and client (like in your case, if the request is actually empty or server is not working fine for any reason): You can use a tiny free (open source) program called **TCPMon** to setup a proxy server that logs all the bytes sent to the server, so that you can investigate what exactly is being transmitted on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got two forms on the same page, so this is why it didn't work. After I removed one, everything started to work.